# Is there any 3rd party apps that can convert azure log file into excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, azure

I'm looking for an application that can convert azure web app log files (which normally open notepad and they look really messy) into a nice excel spreadsheet that is easy for reading. I know it can be done manually, but since I have a lot of log files it would be nice to have an application do that faster.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell or Powershell Core (for Linux) can convert to csv with the "Export-Csv" and "ConvertTo-Csv" (ConvertTo-Csv > filename) cmdlets. Then you can open the files that you created with Excel.

Comment: summertime like I said in the question I know how to do it manually with powershell, I was just wondering whether there is an application that can do it and make my life easier.

Comment: OK, I don't see the word Powershell in your question though. You could just write a profile script that downloads the logs and converts them automatically when you start Powershell or use cron.